# Variadically templated use of std::conditional where one type is an instantiation failure

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am attempting to build a variadically templated class. As is common, each level of the instantiation needs to instantiate the "next level" by slicing off one type and then using the remainder. For my final level, rather than specialize on one type, I'd rather give some base case type and keep from duplicating the actual logic.

I've added a `std::conditional` to switch on the `BaseCase` when the rest of the types consists of an empty parameter pack.

```
class BaseCase { };

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class VariadicClass;

template <typename... Ts>
using NextLevel = typename std::conditional<
    sizeof...(Ts) != 0, VariadicClass<Ts...>, BaseCase>::type;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class VariadicClass {
    T this_level; // whatever
    NextLevel<Ts...> next_level; // fails when Ts is empty
};
```

**The problem** is that `VariadicClass` is templated on at least one type parameter, so when it hits the base case (`Ts` is empty), trying to use `std::conditional` uses `VariadicClass<>`, which fails of course.

The solution I've managed is to write some specific functions and use `decltype` along with overloads, and not use `std::conditional` at all.

```
template <typename... Ts>
VariadicClass<Ts...> type_helper(Ts&&...);

BaseCase type_helper();

template <typename... Ts>
using NextLevel = decltype(type_helper(std::declval<Ts>()...));
```

Now, this works, but if I want to keep up this practice every time I have a variadic class, it seems tedious. Is there a way to use `std::conditional` or something similar to achieve this effect without having to write out so much problem-specific code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defer evaluation.

```
template<class T>struct identity{
  template<class...>using result=T;
};
template<template<class...>class src>
struct delay{
  template<class...Ts>using result=src<Ts...>;
};

template <typename... Ts>
using NextLevel =
typename std::conditional<
  sizeof...(Ts) != 0, delay<VariadicClass>, identity<BaseCase>
>::type::template result<Ts...>;
```

`identity` ignores the `Ts...` and returns its argument.  `delay` takes a `template` and applies the `Ts...`.  While the signature looks suspicious, it works.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just

```
class BaseCase { };

template <typename... Ts>
class VariadicClass; // undefined base template

template <typename... Ts>
using NextLevel = typename std::conditional<
    sizeof...(Ts) != 0, VariadicClass<Ts...>, BaseCase>::type;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class VariadicClass<T, Ts...> { // partial specialization for having at least 1 type parameter
    T this_level; // whatever
    NextLevel<Ts...> next_level;
};
```

Comment: You could also implement `BaseCase` as a `VariardicClass<>` specialization, to get rid of `NextLevel` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

After reading [T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25539512/1013719) and Yakk's comment, I realized I could write this as one templated class with two specializations, rather than write another `BaseClass` and the type alias.

```
template <typename... Ts>
class VariadicClass;

// specialization gets everything but an empty Ts
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class VariadicClass<T, Ts...> {
    VariadicClass<Ts...> next_level;
    // normal case
};

template <>
class VariadicClass<> { // instead of class BaseCase
    // base case
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may specialize `VariadicClass<T>`

```
class BaseCase {};

// general case
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class VariadicClass {
    T this_level; // whatever
    VariadicClass<Ts...> next_level;
};

// specialization
template <typename T>
class VariadicClass<T> {
    T this_level; // whatever
    BaseClass next_level;
};
```

Comment: this is what I was trying to avoid doing